# How to copy paragraph_styles from one document to another in python-docx?

Tags: python-docx

I am working from a template file which is missing some of the base style types from the WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH.
If I list all styles included in the templates WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH I get

```
Normal
header
footer
Matrix Text
Body Text
toc1
Body
Balloon Text
Caption
annotation text
annotation subject
Body Text Indent
EY Document title
footnote text
EY Body text (with para space)
List Paragraph
```

In order to get around this I have created a blank Document object and built a paragraph_styles list object based on the default style types for WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH. This gives me the following style types

```
Normal
Heading 1
Heading 2
Heading 3
Heading 4
Heading 5
Heading 6
Heading 7
Heading 8
Heading 9
No Spacing
Title
Subtitle
List Paragraph
Body Text
Body Text 2
Body Text 3
List
List 2
List 3
List Bullet
List Bullet 2
List Bullet 3
List Number
List Number 2
List Number 3
List Continue
List Continue 2
List Continue 3
macro
Quote
Caption
Intense Quote
TOC Heading
```

The style I want is 'List Bullet' but I cant seem to be able to add the styles from the temp Document to the main Document which is based on the template

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read and understand this page in the documentation:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html

And this one that immediately follows it:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html

Basically you add a paragraph with the desired style to the template, then delete that paragraph, and then save the template.

Setting a paragraph to a "latent" style (such as ListBullet) causes that style to be added to the document. When you delete the paragraph, the style remains. When you save the document, that style is available for later documents that use it as a template.

Comment: just for clarification: all these steps (add/delete paragraph and save template) are to be done in MS Word processor? Or are you meaning this can be done in a computer without Word, using pyhon-docx methods only?

Comment: Yes, good clarification. Probably clear if you read the links, but indeed you need to do the operations in Word (or LibreOffice or whatever) to "materialize" the latent styles.